# Pandas: plot a dataframe with on its right side rectangle colored according to an array's values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have a dataframe with 100 rows and 4 columns. I have an array (size 100,1) filled with values spanning between 0 and 1. I would like to plot my dataframe, with on its right side a rectangle which will take a color depending on the value of the array at a specific row (see the poor drawing I made, the array is written to help understanding what I want). I would like the colors to be a gradient, where 0 = dark blue, and 1 = bright red.
I know how to create a colormap, but this is slightly different.
Which function do you advise me to use ?

Here is some code I use for the plotting:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

rectangle_values = np.random.rand(100)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar = None)
```

[image])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to use `plot.subplots` to create two plots with the `width_ratios` argument as something like 19:1. On the left hand side you plot the data frame as usual, on the right hand side you plot the vector. Notice that I am using `vmin` and `vmax` to set the boundaries as required (0, 1) for the vector. Also, for the requested colors, I'm using `MatPlotLib`'s `RdBu` (Red and Blue map), but it was needed to reverse it in order to meet your requirements. You can confirm the colors by the values, on this run the generated random values were `[0.74, 0.96, 0.87, 0.50, 0.26]`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

rectangle_values = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5), columns=['foo'])

plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [19, 1]})

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.heatmap(df, cbar = None)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.heatmap(rectangle_values, cbar = None, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu').reversed(), vmin=0, vmax=1)

plt.show()
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It put me on the right way ! 
However when I run your code the ratio doesn't work and I obtain two subplots the same size

Comment: Let me know if you were not able to proceed on the matter, I can investigate an alternative solution to `width_ratios` if needed.

Comment: I couldn't make it work, even with other dataframes. I don't understand because I copy/pasted the exact same code (on Spyder, jupyter and Colab) and the subplots are the same size

Comment: I managed to make it work by writing:

`f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2,sharey=False, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [19, 1]})

g1 = sns.heatmap(df, cbar = None, ax=ax1)

g2 = sns.heatmap(rectangle_values,yticklabels=False, cbar = None, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('RdBu').reversed(), vmin=0, vmax=1, ax=ax2)

plt.show()`